# Updating fields in one list from another list

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a better or more efficient way to do this?

Both of these objects have the same Id and some similar fields that I want to update.

```
foreach (var i in oldItems)
{
   foreach (var j in newItemValues)
   {
       if(i.id == j.Id)
       {
           j.field1 = (decimal)i.field1;
           j.field2 = (decimal)i.field2;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Better or more efficient in terms of what, performance, memory consumption, readability?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this maybe you are like this;

```
foreach (var n in newItemValues)
{
    Item item = oldItems.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == n.Id);

    if (item != null)
    {
        n.field1 = item.field1;
        n.field2 = item.field2;
    }
}
```

Edit: If you keep `oldItems` in a HashSet or HashTable by keeping key as Id the time taken will slow to O(N).

Comment: That's O(n^2). Should be used with caution to avoid real slowdowns.

Answer (score 1):

Convert `oldItems` or `newItemValues` into a Map before looping.

That will reduce computational complexity from O(n^2) to O(n)

Comment: This would be a good use case for my new Index class once it is written :)

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by `Linq Query`

```
newItemsValues = 
            (from t1 in oldItems
             join t2 in newItemsValues on t1.Id equals t2.Id
             select new YourModel { field1 =  t1.field1 ,field2 = t1.field2 }
            ).ToList();
```

**result** will a list of all matching items where `oldItems Id` will be equals to `newItemsValues Id`

Comment: I  am not convinced that creating a new list is more efficient.

Comment: Update , simply assign query result to existing list.